# Video server for PS3

Tags: video, streaming, media, mediaserver, ps3

I am trying to get my Ubuntu desktop to be able to share videos so my PS3 can watch them over my network.

I would like a folder,or something similar that I can share as a media center so all of the videos in that folder will be shared and accessible by my PS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install rygel-preferences`

Run rygel-preferences after installing, pick the folders you want to share, and start up rygel.